# Can't find conda at rstudio terminal, while it is workable outside?

Tags: r, tensorflow, anaconda, rstudio

Just trying to use tensorflow-gpu on my notebook, after installing anaconda, VSC++, CUDA, cdnn, and then tensorflow-gpu on conda base environment.
Before the gpu version, I'd using keras(cpu) for a while, so the cpu version is installed, and running well.

My question is, why I can't find r-tensorflow environment, even the `conda` commend in the rstudio terminal does not exist.

the rstudio terminal windows

```
eric1@NB  /g/work/R_Prj/KEK/2019-08-TEST (master)
$ conda
bash: conda: command not found
```

the Anaconda prompt window

```
(base) C:\Users\eric1>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
base                  *  C:\Users\eric1\Anaconda3
```

and both on the same notebook at the same time.
Please advise how I can see conda in the rstudio, and how I can install tensorflow-gpu version in R. Many thanks.